# Type mismatch when returning a child which has a type of the parent class

Tags: java

I have been writing some classes for a framework , and maybe is something not that hard, but I'm stuck.

I have a class that has a generic type method , that help me to return a new instance of a page class:

```
public class LDPages {

    private static <T> T getPage(Class<T> pageClass) {
        T page = null;
        try {
            page = pageClass.newInstance();
            PageFactory.initElements(LocalDriverManager.getDriver(), page);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return page;
    }

    public static TopNavigationPage topNavigation() {
        if(AppSystemProperty.getInstance().getBrowserType().toString().toLowerCase().contains("mobile")) {
            return getPage(TopNavigationPageMobile.class);
        }else {
            return getPage(TopNavigationPage.class);
        }
    }

}
```

Then I have defined a parent class called TopNavigationPage which help me to return a boolean for certain condition

```
public class TopNavigationPage {
    public boolean topNavigationVerifications() {
        return hasFindaLawyerTab() && hasLATLTab() && hasLegalFormsTab()  && hasBlogsTab();
    }
}
```

I override if I have a mobile from the class above.

```
public class TopNavigationPageMobile extends TopNavigationPage{
@Override   
public boolean topNavigationVerifications() {
    Extensions.clickOn(hamburgerMenu);
    return hasFindaLawyerTab() && hasLATLTab() && hasLegalFormsTab()  && hasBlogsTab();
}
}
```

But when I use ,

```
return getPage(TopNavigationPageMobile.class);
```

from the first class(when is mobile and return the child class) I get type mismatch, but I think the relationship is correct, since TopNavigationPageMobile is a TopNavigationPage, ( specific to general ) .Already looked some stackoverflow answers many referring to use the this in the return of parent class.

[image: compilation error as shown in Eclipse]

The traceback error, last 4 lines

```
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Are you getting compilation error or runtime exception ? Can you share the stacktrace

Comment: @Priyak Dey sure, it's compile error , already edited the question with a picture , maybe is just Eclipse messing around.

Comment: It works fine for me. I sometimes see eclipse messing around with the red lines even after removing the errors. Can you close the file and reopen to check again.

Comment: Tried that , and ran it anyways and got : TopNavigationPageMobile cannot be resolved to a type.